# Type 'UploaderEventArgs' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vb.net-2010

I tried the below code to upload a file to sql server table using vb.net command button.  But while clicking build getting error in UploaderEventArgs.

**Type 'UploaderEventArgs' is not defined.**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Protected Sub UploadAttachments1_FileUploaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As UploaderEventArgs)
        'set connection string
        Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString")
        ' Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
        Dim data() As Byte = New Byte((args.FileSize) - 1) {}
        'get file extension
        Dim extensioin As String = args.FileName.Substring((args.FileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1))
        Dim fileType As String = ""
        'set the file type based on File Extension
        Select Case (extensioin)
            Case "doc"
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
            Case "docx"
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
            Case "xls"
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Case "xlsx"
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Case "jpg"
                fileType = "image/jpg"
            Case "png"
                fileType = "image/png"
            Case "gif"
                fileType = "image/gif"
            Case "pdf"
                fileType = "application/pdf"
        End Select
        Dim stream As Stream = args.OpenStream
        'read the file as stream
        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        com.Connection = con
        'set parameters
        Dim p1 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        Dim p2 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@FileType", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        Dim p3 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary)
        p1.Value = args.FileName
        p2.Value = fileType
        p3.Value = data
        com.Parameters.Add(p1)
        com.Parameters.Add(p2)
        com.Parameters.Add(p3)
        com.CommandText = "Insert into Files (Name,FileType,Data) VALUES (@Name,@FileType,@Data)"
        con.Open()
        'insert the file into database
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Source Link to the above code:

http://ajaxuploader.com/h/Save-Files-to-Database-using-FileUpload-Control.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `UploaderEventArgs` is part of the framework the company you linked offers, so you need to download and install it first. It's not part of the regular .NET libraries.